# Hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SQLExceptionHelper log Exception, SQL state null

Tags: jsf, hibernate

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63GDL.png)Estou com esse problema no meu Hibernate session Validade a newly established conection, ao fazer a query, ele perde a sessão, só depois de dar vários F5 a sessão volta.. alguém pode me ajudar? ... segue a imagem do Erro.
[image: hibernate]
1.Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/appjsf" allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Manager 
 className="org.apache.catalina.session.
 PersistentManager"maxActiveSessions="-1" 
 maxIdleBackup="-1" maxIdleSwap="-1" 
 minIdleSwap="-1" saveOnRestart="false">
 <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore"/>
 </Manager>
 <Resources cacheMaxSize="10240000" 
 cacheObjectMaxSize="512000"  cachingAllowed="true"/>
 <Resource name="jdbc/appjsf"
          auth="Container"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appjsf"
          username="deus"
          password="*****"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          maxIdle="233"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
          initialSize="34"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          maxPoolSize="20" 
          minPoolSize="5" 
          acquireIncrement="1" 
          maxActive="300"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          logAbandoned="true"
          validatonQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="34000"    
          abandonWhenPercentageFull="50"
          closeMethod="close" />

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/appjsf"
              global="jdbc/appjsf"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Você pode mostrar seu código que é responsável pela conexão?

Comment: Postei dois links com as imagens dos XML

Comment: Você postou isso como respostas. Altere isso amigo.

Comment: Esse aí é meu arquivo context.xml